# Exported UV Layout is Blank

Tags: uv, export

I'm having an issue with trying to export my UV layout in Blender 2.76b on Windows 10.

My model has seams and is unwrapped and the UV map is working properly. However, when I try to export the UV layout the resulting image has no lines, it's just a blank canvas.

I've been able to successfully export the layout of this project less than a week ago with no noticeable changes other than some adjusted UV coordinates.

Steps I've done to export the layout:

- Switch to UV Editing screen layout
- Change 3D View to Edit Mode
- Select all vertices in 3D View and UV editor
- Go to UVs > Export UV Layout
- Export the layout as a .png with the "All UVs" flag checked

Any assistance in figuring out what's going wrong would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Check that you have the "keep uv and edit mode mesh sync" disabled (in the bottom screen options). I had the same issue and that worked

Comment: If you have this option enabled, only the selected faces will get exported. Simply select everything in edit mode and it'll export them.

Answer (score 1):

Disable "keep uv and edit mode mesh sync", and make sure that the edit mode and UV editor are using the same selection method (vertex, edge, or face select).